# Transactions in Rust Diesel

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm learning Rust and the Rocket framework and am trying to build an application with database connection using Diesel. I've been able to successfully connect to a SqLite db and perform some basic CRUD operations. Now I want to be able to ensure transaction atomicity. For example, I have a user model with a user table and a role table that are in a many-to-many relationship and are joined through a junction table called user_role. So to insert a new user, I do something like this:

```
    let new_user = CreateUser{id: Option::from(new_id), username, email, password_hash: password };
    diesel::insert_into(user::table)
        .values(&new_user)
        .execute(connection)
        .expect("Error saving the user");

    let user_role = CreateUserRole{user_id: new_user.id, role_id: existing_role.id};
    diesel::insert_into(user_role::table)
        .values(&user_role)
        .execute(connection)
        .expect("Could not add role to user");
```

Now the thing is, if there is a problem with the role assignation, the user gets created, but no role is assigned which I don't want to happen. Is there a way to ensure atomicity so that either both operations get performed or none of them. I saw this page in the doc about transaction manager: https://docs.diesel.rs/master/diesel/connection/trait.TransactionManager.html, but I don't really understand how I could use that and I haven't found any example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TransactionManager` is usually the wrong abstraction for building transactions. It is only useful in specific cases, where you want strict control over the transaction.
Usually you want to use [`Connection::transaction`](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/connection/trait.Connection.html#method.transaction) to wrap your operations into a transaction. Anything inside the provided closure is executed in a transaction. The transaction is committed if `Ok` is returned. It will be rolled back if any error is returned. Given your example that would look like

```rust
connection.transaction(|connection| {
    let new_user = CreateUser{id: Option::from(new_id), username, email, password_hash: password };
    diesel::insert_into(user::table)
        .values(&new_user)
        .execute(connection)?;

    let user_role = CreateUserRole{user_id: new_user.id, role_id: existing_role.id};
    diesel::insert_into(user_role::table)
        .values(&user_role)
        .execute(connection)?;

    // That uses `diesel::result::Error` as error type
    // you can use any other error type here as long as
    // it implements `From<diesel::result::Error>`.
    diesel::result::QueryResult::Ok(())
})
```

Comment: Thank your for that! Do you know of any good example/tutorial that covers more than the basic usage of diesel?